# SSRS group not showing all records

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I'm having an issue getting the report to show all the records within the grouping.

[image: Result Set screenshot]

The grouping totals are correct, however it's not showing all the records.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by;

- removing the sorting within the stored proc
- added the headings outside the group (see attached in orange)

http://postimg.org/image/ezdog42jt/